# Syntax for partial function composition

Tags: haskell

```
module Luhn (isValid) where

import qualified Data.Char as C

isAsciiAlpha :: Char -> Bool
isAsciiAlpha = C.isAsciiLower || C.isAsciiUpper

isValid :: String -> Bool
isValid n
  | any ((isAsciiAlpha || C.isSpace) . not) n = False
  | otherwise = ys > 1 && sum xxs `mod` 10 == 0
  where
    xs = reverse [c | c <- n, isAsciiAlpha c]
    ys = length xs
    zs = zip xs (cycle [1, 2])
    xxs = [convert x y | (x, y) <- zs]

convert :: Char -> Int -> Int
convert c mul =
  do
    let n = C.digitToInt c
    case () of
      _
        | mul == 2 && (n > 4) -> n * mul - 9
        | otherwise -> n * mul
```

I'm struggling with this line: `any ((isAsciiAlpha || C.isSpace) . not) n = False`. What I want is pretty obvious; find if any of the characters is something other than an ASCII alphabet or a space.

In spite of trying various syntaxes, I keep getting compilation error on this line, something like

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’
                  with actual type ‘Char -> Bool’
```

Comment: This should be `not . (\c -> isAsciiAlpha c || C.isSpace c) . not)`, or `not . (liftA2 (||) isAsciiAlpha isSpace)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Two `not`??

Comment: no that was a typo: the `not` should be put *before* the lambda expression, since it is a post-processing step on the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use [**`(||) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-124--124-) on two functions: the parameters should be both `Bool`s. What you can do is construct a function that maps a character `c` on `isAsciiAlpha c || C.isSpace c`, so `\c -> isAsciiAlpha c || C.isSpace c`, or you can use [**`liftA2 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:liftA2) with `liftA2 (||) isAsciiAlpha C.isSpace`. The [**`not :: Bool -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:not) should also be applied on the *result* of the function, so:

```
import Control.Applicative(liftA2)

isAsciiAlpha :: Char -> Bool
isAsciiAlpha = liftA2 (||) C.isAsciiLower C.isAsciiUpper

isValid :: String -> Bool
isValid n
  | any (not . liftA2 (||) isAsciiAlpha C.isSpace) n = False
  | otherwise = ys > 1 && sum xxs `mod` 10 == 0
  where -- …
```

You can also make use of [**`(<||>) :: Applicative a => a Bool -> a Bool -> a Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/protolude-0.3.2/docs/Protolude.html#v:-60--124--124--62-) or its shortcircuitng version [**`(||^) :: Monad m => m Bool -> m Bool -> m Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/protolude-0.3.2/docs/Protolude.html#v:-124--124--94-) of the [**`protolude`** package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/protolude/).

Comment: I prefer the simpler lambda version, but still can't get it to compile. `any not . (\c -> (isAsciiAlpha c) || (C.isSpace c)) n` fails, and any combination of parentheses doesn't fix it.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar: you need to use parenthesis so `any (not . (\c -> isAsciiAlpha c || C.isSpace c)) n`

Comment: Have you tried it yourself? I did that already, but `Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘Char -> Bool’`

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar: that's because you have the same situation for the `isAsciiAlpha` function.